# Using golang-ci-lint in circleci

Tags: bash, go, makefile, circleci

I've a `Makefile` which is running some targets on circleci
This is the target of the `Makefile`

```
install_lint:
    curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh| sh -s v1.21.0
```

When I run on the second target `golangci-lint --version` I got error `golangci-lint: Command not found`

I tried also with this

`curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh| sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin v1.21.0`

as Im runnig docker `1.13.2`

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/golang:1.13.3
```

Any idea what am I missing here ? how to make the binary usable ?

I've also tried something like

```
install_lint:

    curl -sLO https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/releases/download/v${GOLANGCI_VERSION}/golangci-lint-${GOLANGCI_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz
    tar -xzvf golangci-lint-${GOLANGCI_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz
    cp golangci-lint-${GOLANGCI_VERSION}-linux-amd64/golangci-lint /usr/local/bin/golangci-lint && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/golangci-lint
```

and I got error

`cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/golangci-lint': Permission denied`

Comment: Why not use the official [golangci-lint Docker images](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/releases)?

Comment: https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/gotest/tools#commands-install-golangci-lint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is

1- I let circle CI install golangci-lint

`curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh| sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin v1.20.0`

2- My make file only has the golangci-lint call

```
lint: 
    @golangci-lint run
```

3-Circle CI step call my makefile

```
validate-lint:
    ...
    steps:
      - run:
          name: "Validate lint"
          command: |
            curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh| sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin v1.20.0
            make lint
```